# How to rename variables in multidimensional data frame (>3000 columns) using existing variables?

Tags: r, data-wrangling

Thank you @Jon Spring for helpful suggestion. Following Jon's suggestion, I edited my post. I added brief example of my data frames and `dput()` of them.

#Question:

I am a newbie in R programming and trying to make a multidimensional data frame to be analyzable.
My data frame `wc_raw_data` has 83 rows and 3062 columns which includes 1530 chemicals as shown below.

```
> wc_raw_data <- read_xlsx(wc_raw_file, sheet=2, skip=1, col_names = F)

> wc_raw_data
# A tibble: 82 x 3,062
.
.
```

```
> wc_raw_data[1:6,1:6]
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  ...1        ...2                     ...3                    ...4      ...5                        ...6     
  <chr>       <chr>                    <chr>                   <chr>     <chr>                       <chr>    
1 NA          Analyte                  1,2,4-Trichlorobenzene  NA        1,2-Dibromo-3-chloropropane NA       
2 NA          CAS Number               120-82-1                NA        96-12-8                     NA       
3 NA          Molecular Weight (g/mol) 181.447                 NA        236.333                     NA       
4 Sample Name Sample Number            Concentration (pMol/WB) Qualifier Concentration (pMol/WB)     Qualifier
5 CAS 001     A191916                  <276                    U         <423                        U        
6 CAS 002     A191917                  <276                    U         <423                        U
```

Since it seems combined two different data frame, eg [1:3,] contain "Analyte", "CAS Number" and Molecular Weight" in rows and [4:82,]contain   "Sample Name", "Sample Number", Concentration (pMol/WB)" and "Qualifiers" in columns. I split data frame into two `wc_chemicals` and `wc_raw_df` and they look like:

```
> wc_chemicals[1:3,1:6]
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  ...1  ...2                     ...3                   ...4  ...5                        ...6 
  <lgl> <chr>                    <chr>                  <lgl> <chr>                       <lgl>
1 NA    Analyte                  1,2,4-Trichlorobenzene NA    1,2-Dibromo-3-chloropropane NA   
2 NA    CAS Number               120-82-1               NA    96-12-8                     NA   
3 NA    Molecular Weight (g/mol) 181.447                NA    236.333                     NA
```

```
> wc_raw_df[1:6, 1:6]
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  ...1        ...2          ...3                    ...4      ...5                    ...6     
  <chr>       <chr>         <chr>                   <chr>     <chr>                   <chr>    
1 Sample Name Sample Number Concentration (pMol/WB) Qualifier Concentration (pMol/WB) Qualifier
2 CAS 001     A191916       <276                    U         <423                    U        
3 CAS 002     A191917       <276                    U         <423                    U        
4 CAS 003     A191918       <276                    U         <423                    U        
5 CAS 004     A191919       <276                    U         <423                    U        
6 CAS 005     A191920       <276                    U         <423                    U
```

`dput()` of selected data frames:

```
> dput(wc_chemicals[1:3,1:6])
structure(list(...1 = c(NA, NA, NA), ...2 = c("Analyte", "CAS Number", 
"Molecular Weight (g/mol)"), ...3 = c("1,2,4-Trichlorobenzene", 
"120-82-1", "181.447"), ...4 = c(NA, NA, NA), ...5 = c("1,2-Dibromo-3-chloropropane", 
"96-12-8", "236.333"), ...6 = c(NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
> dput(wc_raw_df[1:6,1:6])
structure(list(...1 = c("Sample Name", "CAS 001", "CAS 002", 
"CAS 003", "CAS 004", "CAS 005"), ...2 = c("Sample Number", "A191916", 
"A191917", "A191918", "A191919", "A191920"), ...3 = c("Concentration (pMol/WB)", 
"<276", "<276", "<276", "<276", "<276"), ...4 = c("Qualifier", 
"U", "U", "U", "U", "U"), ...5 = c("Concentration (pMol/WB)", 
"<423", "<423", "<423", "<423", "<423"), ...6 = c("Qualifier", 
"U", "U", "U", "U", "U")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I wanted to use the **existing names of chemicals** in column names shown as `Analyte` in `wc_chemicals[1,3:3062]` to rename columns named as "**Concentraion**" and "**Qualifier**" in `wc_raw_df`.
For example, I wanted to use "**1,2,4-Trichlorobenzene**" `wc_chemicals[1,3]` to rename "Concentration (pMol/WB)"`wc_raw_df[1, 3]` and "Quantifier"`wc_raw_df[1, 4]`.
My goal is to make data frame having columns look like "1,2,4-Trichlorobenzene Concentration"`wc_raw_df[1, 3, "1,2,4-Trichlorobenzene Qualifier"`wc_raw_df[1, 4]`, "1,2-Dibromo-3-chloropropane Concentration"` wc_raw_df[1, 5]`, "1,2-Dibromo-3-chloropropane Qualifier"` wc_raw_df[1, 6], . . . "Phosphamidon II concentration" `wc_raw_df[1, 3061]`, and "Phosphamidon II Qualifier" `wc_raw_df[1,3062]`.

I found some examples use vectors after assigning old names and new names to rename, but I think there is better way than rename 3060 column names individually. I wonder if anyone can teach me better way. Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you can provide a sample of your data or data in the same format, e.g. by including the output of `dput(wc_chemicals[1:6,1:6]` and  `dput(wc_raw_df[1:6,1:6]` in the text of your question. That prevents ambiguity and reduces the need for others to re-type & reformat so they can try out potential solutions for you.

Comment: @Jon Spring Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
# extract row 1 values from col 3 to the end                                                                                              
wc_chem_names <- as.character(wc_chemicals[1, 3:(ncol(wc_chemicals))])


library(dplyr)
# extracted values from above + alternating Conc / Qual
col_names <- tibble(chem = wc_chem_names, 
                    cat = rep(c("Concentration", "Qualifier"), 
                              length.out = length(wc_chem_names))) %>%
  mutate(chem = if_else(chem == "NA", lag(chem), chem),
         chem_combo = paste(chem, cat)) %>%
  pull(chem_combo)

# Assign those values to the column headers
names(wc_raw_df)[3:ncol(wc_raw_df)] <- col_names
```

Result on example data:

```
> wc_raw_df
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  ...1        ...2          `1,2,4-Trichlorobenzene Concentration` `1,2,4-Trichlorobenzene Qualifier` `1,2-Dibromo-3-chloropropane Concentration` `1,2-Dibromo-3-chloropropane Qualifier`
  <chr>       <chr>         <chr>                                  <chr>                              <chr>                                       <chr>                                  
1 Sample Name Sample Number Concentration (pMol/WB)                Qualifier                          Concentration (pMol/WB)                     Qualifier                              
2 CAS 001     A191916       <276                                   U                                  <423                                        U                                      
3 CAS 002     A191917       <276                                   U                                  <423                                        U                                      
4 CAS 003     A191918       <276                                   U                                  <423                                        U                                      
5 CAS 004     A191919       <276                                   U                                  <423                                        U                                      
6 CAS 005     A191920       <276                                   U                                  <423                                        U
```